# How to get value from a map stored on a httpsession when running on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, logging, tomcat6, tomcat-valve

With Tomcat, it is possible to dump a pile of interesting information to the a logfile by configuring the appropriate valve.

For example:

```
       <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" 
        directory="logs"  
        prefix="localhost." 
        suffix=".txt" 
        pattern='%s %b %I %{myname}s' 
        resolveHosts="false"/>
```

means:

- %s - output HTTP status code of the response
- %b - output Bytes sent,excluding HTTP headers, or '-' if zero
- %I - threadId

and %{myname}s meaning output the value of the attribute myname stored on the session.

All good.  If I have a hashmap stored on my session, I can output by doing something like:

```
%{mymap}s
```

See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/valve.html for more info.

But, I want to just output a value for a specific key, not the entire map.  I have tried:

```
%{mymap.myatt}s
```

But this does not work. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Looking in the source for [`AccessLogValve`](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc6.0.x/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/valves/AccessLogValve.java), search for the String `SessionAttributeElement`. This is what the value is doing to translate your `%{mymap}s` to a string, and it does not look like you can drill down into the map.

You could extend this class and override the `createAccessLogElement` method to add in another handler for a different pattern (lets say `%{mymap.myatt}m`), and then handle the logic in a similar fashion to the `SessionAttributeElement` class, but split the header into the session attribute name and map key.